# Did my teacher make a mistake on this exam code? (Java, For Loops)

Tags: java, for-loop

I recently had this question on a Java exam:

**What is the value of sum after the following nested loop:**

```
int sum = 0;
   for (int i=0; i <= 2; i++)
      for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
         sum=sum + i + j;
```

I put "0" because the loops would not compile, leaving sum with its original value. I got the question wrong. She said the correct answer is 9. Is this correct? I tried it in BlueJ and got errors.

And I doubled checked every character twice before I posted this. It is exactly identical to my test paper. Nothing was omitted or removed.

Comment: She is correct, I just ran it. Copy-paste and executed. Nothing changed. I suggest you manually go trough the steps on a piece of paper. Why would this not compile, by the way?

Comment: Why do you think this code won't compile? Why didn't you try it yourself before asking?

Comment: If the code would not compile then it wouldn't run and you wouldn't get 0 in any case. do a step by step execution on paper. See what happens.

Comment: `I tried it in BlueJ and got errors` It is always a good idea to post errors themselves, so we got a clue on what's happening.

Comment: OP here. I received the error "cannot find symbol - variable i" on the fourth line of code.

Comment: any chance that you've added a `;` too much like in http://ideone.com/g2Xg9R

Comment: Compiles and runs for me in Eclipse. [Makoto's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20390972/464306) explains why it's syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Compiles for me and I get 9.  BlueJ may be giving you warnings about bad indentation but those are only warnings.

Answer (score 1):

your teacher is right. here is the step to calculate:

```
i   j   j<=i    sum
___________________
0   1   false   0       //sum=sum + i + j; not executed since j <= i is false. loop end, return to first for loop
1   1   true    0+1+1=2
1   2   false   2       //sum=sum + i + j; not executed since j <= i is false. loop end, return to first for loop
2   1   true    2+2+1=5
2   2   true    5+2+2=9
```

final value of `sum` = `9`

Answer (score 1):

First - nothing about that code is syntatically incorrect.

You are permitted to have a for-statement without braces, with the caveat that only the *next* statement is executed as part as the implied block.

Since the next line of the first `for` statement is another `for` statement, then your have, in essence, a nested for-loop.

Second, the answer itself is also correct.  The inner loop will not fire until `i > 0`, so you wind up with this:

1. i = 0, j = 1, sum = 0
2. i = 1, j = 1, sum = 2
3. i = 2, j = 1, sum = 5

   1. i = 2, j = 2, sum = 9

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this code is in a main method it will work. If you try to compile just what you wrote obviously it will crash.

After the first loop for as there are no brackets only the first line after it will be executed in loop, which is another loop. This loop will be considered by the compiler as only one line, so the inner content of the second loop will be executed as well by the first loop, and that makes:

0 (second loop is not executed as i=0 < j=1) + 2 (i=1, j=1, second loop executed once) + 7 (3+4) (i=2, j=1, j=2, second loop executed twice) = 9